# 412 error when if/else behaves as intended

Tags: javascript, angular, http, error-handling, zone

I have an Angular `snackBar` that correctly displays an `Error` message if certain conditions are met, and a `Succcess` message if the conditions pass.

However, Zone.js in the console is displaying a 412 error ("Precondition failed") only if the `Error` snackbar pops up.

Is the error related to something in my code, or something else? If it's code-related, what can I do to combat it? If it's server-related, can I do anything?

I'm pretty new to Angular so if there's another snippet that I should provide, then let me know.

**Code sample:**

```
// file: x-mgmt.component.ts

xyz$.subscribe(
      (response: ABCResponse) => {
        if (response?.validationMessages.length) {
          console.log(response.validationMessages)
          this.snackBar.open(`Error`, null, { panelClass: 'error', duration: 3000 });
          this.isFormSubmitted = false;
        } else {
          this.snackBar.open(`Success`, null, { panelClass: 'success', duration: 3000 });
        }
        this.dismiss();
      },
// etc
```

```
// console.log:

[
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "category": "Invalid",
        "name": "ABC",
        "text": "Invalid combination",
        "value": null
    }
]
```

Comment: the error is a HTTP response statues to some request to some server - that's what HTTP response statuses are - the console.log is presumably telling you that the request was sent with an "Invalid combination" - I say presumably because I have no idea what the request is - it could be your code that is sending an "invalid combination" - again, no idea